# How to get a list of typed value for an option in Apache common cli

Tags: apache-commons-cli

I am trying to get a Long[] from the option. Here is my option definition:

```
option optUId = Option.builder("u").
                hasArg().type(Number.class).valueSeparator(',').
                numberOfArgs(500).desc("User ID").build();
```

It can take a comma separate user list.
If I use getParsedOptionValue, it only returns the first one option value. 
If I use getOptionValues, it returns a String[]. Is there a way to get a Long[] back?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Commons-CLI does not support this as it cannot know how you would convert more complex types of Object, you will need to convert the String[] to Long[] in your code.